# JSF 2.0 + Bean Validation + More Validation Groups In One Form

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation, validationgroup

I'm trying to create form for editing entity object when selected from datatable. So when user clicks commandButton in datatable, `myBean.person` property is filled with appropriate person object. Person has "status" property.

I'd like to validate edit form with different validation groups according to value of "status" property. Is this possible?

I created two different validation groups:

```
 @Entity
    public class Person{
        private String status;
        ...
        @NotNull(message = "{person.null.name}", groups = PersonNew.class)
        private String name;
        @NotNull(message = "{person.null.code}", groups = PersonActive.class)
        private String code;
    }
```

I'd like to validate form before saving and when status is "new", then `name` property should be set. When status is "active", then `code` property should be set.

I have jsf page:

```
<h:form id="personEdit">
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.person.name}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.person.code}" />
    ... other fields for other properties ...
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{myBean.save}" />
</h:form>
```

I tried to use `<f:validateBean />` tag with dynamicaly set validationGroups attribute, but method that returned validationGroups was called before actual person object was retrieved. So I couldn't decide according to `Person.status` property.

So is it possible to define `PersonNew` as validation group if person has status "new", otherwise define `PersonActive` as validation group?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My solution for this problem is to validate bean manually. In "save" method I can decide which validation group to use and create Validator to validate given bean. I can create faces messages from returned constraint violations or actually save the Person.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Hibernate Validator than looks like `@GroupSequenceProvider` should satisfy your needs:

> The @GroupSequence annotation is a standardized Bean Validation annotation [...] it allows you to statically redefine the default group sequence for a class. Hibernate Validator also offers a custom, non standardized annotation - org.hibernate.validator.group.GroupSequenceProvider - which allows for dynamic redefinition of the default group sequence.

See [official manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e1053).